# Access to custom field in user registration wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created a simple CreateUserWizard to register my users. I've added 2 TextBox : LastName and FirstName.

Now, I would like to add them in my database when the user is registrated.
Here is what I've done :

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" RequireEmail="false">
  <WizardSteps>
    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="RegisterUserWizardStep0" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        [...]
        <asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="S'inscrire"
          ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
```

And in the .cs file :

```
 protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   TextBox test = RegisterUser.FindControl("LastName") as TextBox;
   // Or using the generated ID
   TextBox test2 = RegisterUser.FindControl("MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_LastName") as TextBox;
 }
```

But whatever I try, my TextBox is always `null`...

Did I miss something ? How could I get the value of these TextBox ?

**Edit :** 
This solution worked for me :

```
(TextBox)RegisterUser.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("CreateUserStepContainer").FindControl("LastName");
```

The only problem is I found the container name "CreateUserStepContainer" by using the debugger...

Comment: I'm sorry, I used the Wizard control instead of CreateUserWizard (shouldn't work on Saturdays). Why do you not access the UserName property directly? Do you really need to access the textbos? (I provided the solution in my answer).

Comment: Actually, the UserName contains the email address in my code. The LastName and FirstName are custom fields from an extension of ProfileBase. And I can't access them directly (like you do for the UserName) because they are not default fields of the CreateUserWizard. (not sure if I'm really clear...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me :

```
(TextBox)RegisterUser.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("CreateUserStepContainer").FindControl("LastName");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to find the control from `CreateUserWizard.CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.control`
 do like this:

```
 TextBox test = (TextBox)RegisterUser.RegisterUserWizardStep0.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName");
```

Comment: As I said to slfan, I can't access `RegisterUserWizardStep0` directly. Based on what you said, I've tried `TextBox t = (TextBox) RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.Wizard.TemplateControl.FindControl("LastName");`. But it doesn't work better...